# Regex replace: Transform pattern with a custom function

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Let's say I have some text such as this:

> [MyAppTerms.TermName1]. [MyAppTerms.TermName2]. 1- [MyAppTerms.TermNameX] 2- ...

I want to replace every occurrence of `[MyAppTerms.Whatever]` with the result of `ReadTerm( "MyAppTerms.Whatever" )`, where `ReadTerm` is a static function which receives a term name and returns the term text for the current language.

Is this feasible using `Regex.Replace`? (alternatives are welcome). I'm looking into substitution groups but I'm not sure if I can use functions with them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) overload.

```
static void Main()
{
    string input = "[MyAppTerms.TermName1]. [MyAppTerms.TermName2]. 1- [MyAppTerms.TermNameX] 2";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[MyAppTerms\.([^\]]+)\]");
    string output = regex.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(RegexReadTerm));

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

static string RegexReadTerm(Match m)
{
    // The term name is captured in the first group
    return ReadTerm(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

The pattern `\[MyAppTerms\.([^\]]+)\]` matches your `[MyAppTerms.XXX]` tags and captures the `XXX` in a capture group. This group is then retrieved in your `MatchEvaluator` delegate and passed to your actual `ReadTerm` method.

It's even better with lambda expressions (since C# 3.0):

```
static void Main()
{
    string input = "[MyAppTerms.TermName1]. [MyAppTerms.TermName2]. 1- [MyAppTerms.TermNameX] 2";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[MyAppTerms\.([^\]]+)\]");
    string output = regex.Replace(input, m => ReadTerm(m.Groups[1].Value));

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Here, you define the evaluator straight inside the code which uses it (keeping logically connected pieces of code together) while the compiler takes care of constructing that `MatchEvaluator` delegate.

Comment: This is a perfect case where a lambda expression gives slightly neater code, IMHO. `regex.Replace(input, match => ReadTerm(match));`

Comment: @Mels Very good point, although you probably want to pass only `m.Groups[1].Value` to `ReadTerm` instead of the whole `Match`. Answer updated.

Comment: You don't even need that syntax for the lambda. if the function takes one parameter, then you can do this: `regex.Replace(input, ReadTerm);`