# convert non alphanumeric glyphs to unicode while preserving alphanumeric

Tags: c#

I need to convert non alpha-numeric glyphs in a string to their unicode value, while preserving the alphanumeric characters. Is there a method to do this in C#?

As an example, I need to convert this string:

`"hello world!"`

To this:

`"hello_x0020_world_x0021_"`

Comment: This was a decent question IMHO. I don't understand why someone would downvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get string safe for XML node name you should use [XmlConver.EncodeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Note that if you need to encode *all* non-alphanumeric characters you'd need to write it yourself as "_" is not encoded by that method.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with this code using LINQ `Select` extension method:

```
  string str = "hello world!";
  string a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  a += a.ToLower();

  char[] alphabet = a.ToCharArray();

  str = string.Join("",
    str.Select(ch => alphabet.Contains(ch) ? 
         ch.ToString() : String.Format("_x{0:x4}_", ch)).ToArray()
  );
```

Now clearly it has some problems:

- it does linear search in the list of characters
- missed numeric...
- if we add numeric need to decide if first character is ok to be digit (assuming yes)
- code creates large number of strings that are immediately discarded (one per character)
- alphanumeric is limited to ASCII (assuming ok, if not `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` to help)
- does to much work for pure alpha-numeric strings

First two are easy - we can use `HashSet` (O(1) `Contains`)  initialized by full list of characters (if any alpahnumeric characters are ok more readable to use existing method - `Char.IsLetterOrDigit`):

```
public static HashSet<char> asciiAlphaNum = new HashSet<char>
       ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
```

To avoid `ch.ToString()` that really pointlessly produces strings for immediate GC we need to figure out how to construct string from mix of `char` and `string`. `String.Join` does not work because it wants strings to start with, regular `new string(...)` does not have option for mix of `char` and `string`. So we are left with `StringBuilder` that happily takes both to `Append`. Consider starting with initial size `str.Length` if most strings don't have other characters.

So for each character we just need to either `builder.Append(ch)` or `builder.AppendFormat(("_x{0:x4}_", (int)ch)`. To perform iteration it is easier to just use regular `foreach`, but if one really wants LINQ - `Enumerable.Aggregate` is the way to go.

```
string ReplaceNonAlphaNum(string str)
{
   var builder = new StringBuilder(); 
   foreach (var ch in str)
   {
       if (asciiAlphaNum.Contains(ch))
             builder.Append(ch);
       else
             builder.AppendFormat("_x{0:x4}_", (int)ch);
   }
   return builder.ToString();    
}

string ReplaceNonAlphaNumLinq(string str)
{
   return str.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder, ch) => 
       asciiAlphaNum.Contains(ch) ? 
          builder.Append(ch) : builder.AppendFormat("_x{0:x4}_", (int)ch)           
   ).ToString();
}
```

To the last point - we don't really need to do anything if there is nothing to convert - so some check like [check alphanumeric characters in string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183379/check-alphanumeric-characters-in-string-in-c-sharp) would help to avoid extra strings.

**Thus final version (LINQ as it is a bit shorter and fancier):**

```
private static asciiAlphaNumRx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
public static HashSet<char> asciiAlphaNum = new HashSet<char>
       ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");

string ReplaceNonAlphaNumLinq(string str)
{
   return asciiAlphaNumRx.IsMatch(str) ? str :
       str.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder, ch) => 
          asciiAlphaNum.Contains(ch) ? 
             builder.Append(ch) : builder.AppendFormat("_x{0:x4}_", (int)ch)            
       ).ToString();
}
```

Alternatively whole thing could be done with Regex - see [Regex replace: Transform pattern with a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747919/regex-replace-transform-pattern-with-a-custom-function) for starting point.

Comment: Looks very half-done... should use `new HashSet<char>("az09AZ")` and `String.Format("_x{0:x4}_", ch)`... or maybe use Regex replace with callback...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for remarks. But I don't understand why it is half-way done. It gives expected result.

Comment: I've made some minor edit to the post showing what I mean since it did not fit into a comment. Feel free to revert. If you fine with the change I think now it covers a all OP may be interested in and deserves upvote :)